# Compatibility for ASUS ZenBook Pro UX550VE

Tags: asus, compatibility

I'm looking at buying a new laptop and I want to run Linux full time. I was looking at [this laptop](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-Pro-UX550VE/Tech-Specs/) and I wanted to know if it's hardware would be compatible and if the finger print sensor would work.

Answer (score 4):

I just got this model today and I installed Ubuntu 18.04 (daily build, downloaded from [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/HEADER.html)). Everything worked just fine during the installation (sound, touch pad etc). When Ubuntu installer needed to reboot, that failed. Stucked with message "soft lockup, CPU#1 stuck for 22s!"

Installed latest kernel and latest Nvidia drivers (apt update ; apt install nvidia-384), that fixed the shutdown/reboot issue.

Fingerprint reader is **not** supported. The drivers are closed source and from what I found [this person](https://github.com/sbechet/libfprint) is trying to make it supported.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! How have you been able to install an Ubuntu release `18.04` which isn't even released yet?... Don't shout `IT WORKED` and don't tell us what `did not help`. Please instead edit your answer and reduce it to the neccessary facts to answer the OP's question

Comment: @derHugo: Just a quick advice: please reserve code formatting for things that are identifiers, source code, listings, or generally things that are produced by or meant to be interpreted by a computer program. If you want to highlight or quote words or proper nouns (e. g. application names) in the context of natural (English) language please enclose them in underscores (`_`), asterisks (`*`), or quotation marks. There's not always a clear line but this comment of yours is clearly a case of misuse.

Comment: @derHugo I was writing the post while I was trying to fix the computer, sorry for my excitement and that some things worked and did not work. I will update the answer and also add a download link to Ubuntu 18.04.  Of course it's not the final release, but a daily build.

Comment: @Robban, how's battery life on that laptop?

Comment: @Paul I think it's pretty great. When using the computer for browsing and simpler tasks, the battery life is really good. But when i start my Docker environment and other CPU heavy applications, the battery will last for aprox 2 hours. :-)

Comment: @Robban could you please comment which kernel do you use exactly? I still to make the same laptop with ubuntu 18.04 to work completely. The most severe issue is that it does not suspend on lid closure or power-button press. The screen goes off, but the fans run same speed, battery is drained quick (slower than running, but almost empty after being disconnected for a night) and it HEATS like crazy (also in running)