# Asus zenbook pro UX550VE: Sound either muted or very loud

Tags: nvidia, sound, asus

I have a new Asus zenbook pro UX550VE.

I downloaded Ubuntu 17.10 with Gnome, and installed it using the default options (erasing Windows).

I face an issue with my sound: It has only 2 states: either muted, or very loud. It makes no difference if the volume line a bit above the mute level, or at max volume.

I was facing a problem with shutting down the computer too, and I had to use nvidia drivers to solve it (solution found at [Compatibility for ASUS ZenBook Pro UX550VE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967002/compatibility-for-asus-zenbook-pro-ux550ve))

But the sound issue remains, with both Xorg and nvidia drivers.

Any help truly appreciated!

EDIT: headphones work fine, only the laptop speakers behave strange.

EDIT 2: I installed ALSA mixer, and noticed that changing Master has no effect at all for the built-in speakers, but changing PCM does the job. But this does not solve the problem, since my keyboard and sound bar on top-right corner of the screen are connected with Master, not PCM.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you should do, since ~90% of the hardware-related error posts here have to do with graphics drivers (especially Nvidia). Try to find drivers for the sound and any other problematic hardware on Ubuntu's repositories or on ASUS websites. Feel free to contact me.

Comment: How can I find and test additional drivers for sound?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1721345  (comment #8)

I edited the file /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common (with sudo).

I added the following lines **before** the [Element PCM] block:

```
[Element Master]
switch = mute
volume = ignore
```

and run in terminal:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

and that solved the problem. Both headphones and built-in speakers work fine.

Comment: Glad you found the solution!

Comment: I can confirm that this works on Arch Linux (pulseaudio 13-dirty, linux 5.4.5) on my Asus ZenBook UX490U. Now I can listen to Deicide while coding. Thanks.

Comment: When I do this, my audio jack stops working. The laptop doesn't even detect the headphones. Any idea what to do?

Comment: I also had this while running Arch on a Framework laptop (PulseAudio 16.1, Linux 5.15.50-1-lts). Thanks for the solution! I hope this solution can contribute a patch that can be merged somewhere. But is the bug in PulseAudio or in Linux?